# How to handle `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` straight after Windows Login with Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I have a Mac that runs macOS High Sierra, and a Boot Camp with Windows 10 that used to be running and up to date. But now, when I try to open Windows environment, I have got a blue screen with a `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` error message straight after I enter my Windows password. How can I get past this error message and open Windows,  with or without reinstallation, whatever is doable/easier.

I have tried to use the Boot Camp assistant (under OS X), but I get an error message `The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.`

I have checked my partition and the possible issue is that I have an additional, 3rd partition disk, called "Windows recovery". I am unable to remove it even in OS X recovery mode ("-" is greyed).

I have tried to run `sudo gpt -r show disk0` as per [Cannot delete partition (minus greyed out) - non-encrypted, no core storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216669) but I get an error message `gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': Operation not permitted` even though I am currently using an admin account.

What could I do to be able to open my Windows?
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you intent to reinstall Windows? The Windows Recovery partition is probably not the problem. A normal Boot Camp Assistant installation of Windows 10 includes the creation of this partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson:  I cannot open the Boot Camp assistant, see the first screenshot for the error message. It was my starting point, the following is the investigation of the reasons why I cannot open it.

I am trying to get Windows to work, with or without reinstallation, whatever is doable/easier.

Comment: The only reason to open the Boot Camp Assistant would be to remove Windows from your Mac. I see you are using the new APFS format. Many users have reported problems with the Boot Camp Assistant when APFS in involved. What you should try to do is boot to the Windows Recovery partition and use the Microsoft tools in an attempt to repair Windows 10. I am currently entering an answer with instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suppose to use the software installed in the Window Recovery partition when something goes wrong with Windows. You stated in your question that Windows crashes after logging in. If so, then try this.

> Note: To get a better view of an image, either click on the image or open the image in a new window.

1. Boot to Windows 10.
2. In the login window, hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while selecting "Restart", as shown below.

   [image: x1]
3. If prompted with the message shown below, select "Restart anyway".

   [image: x2]
4. With any luck, you should get the window shown below. Select "Troubleshoot".

   [image: x3]
5. In the window shown below, you could select "Reset this PC", but first I would select "Advanced options".

   [image: x4]
6. You should now see the Advanced Options window shown below.

   [image: x5]

   Below is a description of these options.

   - "System Restore" - If Window Update downloaded software that caused your problem, the this may be a good choice. Note: there may not be any restore points.
   - "System Image Recovery" - You can use this option if you previous made an image file.
   - "Startup Repair" - You can try this option, but usually this does not repair problems of the type you are describing.
   - "Command Prompt" - You can skip this choice.
   - "Startup Settings" - This will allow change boot options at startup. This may allow you to boot Windows, but the problem will not be fixed.
   - "Go back to the previous version" - This requires that you have a previous version to return to. This usually only works if you have recently upgraded. In my option, this would be a last choice.

   If none of these options appeal to you, select the arrow and try "Reset this PC".

Comment: If this answer does not repair Windows and you wish manually reinstall Windows, please post a comment below.

Comment: Thanks! did not realise the F8 -> Shift change